# I need to get the values of Sharepoint Field Choice Column in Sharepoint 2007 without accessing a list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I want to do this but without accesing the list "items", that is to say, to access the column perhaps with the root site or a contenttype, not depending on a list that can be created or not inside the Sharepoint app.

```
SPFieldChoice choice = (SPFieldChoice)items.Fields[namefield];

                foreach (string choiceName in choice.Choices)
                {
                  //etc...
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `web.Fields` or `ContentTypes[typeName].Fields`:

```
SPWeb web = ... ;

SPFieldChoice choice = (SPFieldChoice)web.Fields[namefield];
```

or

```
SPFieldChoice choice = (SPFieldChoice)web.ContentTypes[typeName].Fields[namefield];
```